# Issues after using SD card as internal storage in Android Marshmallow

Tags: internal-storage, external-sd, 6.0-marshmallow, adoptable-storage

I got an update for Android 6.0 Marshmallow, and there's an option to use the SD card as internal storage. I did that and am now able to install apps, etc to it. But the problem is, all the apps which needed an SD card stopped working (e.g. Camera, Whatsapp, etc.)

Any workaround for this, like enabling this app to use the internal memory instead? Couldn't find such an option anywhere in the Settings.

Comment: Even after you use sd card as internal, some apps still use original internal storage like flickr, googl+..etc. Did you twek your app to use sd card before? In that case, you must first revert it back  before making sd card as `"internal"`

Answer (score 2):

The card can only be used as internal storage. If you try to eject the card and read it on a computer, it won’t work. **All data on the card will also be erased, so you have to take back up anything important first**. **So there is no way to revert back**.

Comment: As soon as you remove the SD card your data is gone? I'm amazed the Android team implemented such a hazardous approach.

Answer (score 0):

Format your microSD Card as internal storage (there is an option in the menu) before using it as Internal Storage.

If that doesn't work, try rebooting the phone.

Answer (score 0):

In marshmallow once you install it I will copy the apps. But those app will be in internal storage only it will ask you like to move pictures audio any any other storages . might be you got moved up with your apps . try restore to phone internal storage or reinstall .